# XSL 1.0 Need to output a list across then down

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml code:

```
<section>
  <text>
    <list>
      <item>Item 1</item>
      <item>Item 2</item>
      <item>Item 3</item>
      <item>Item 4</item>
      <item>Item 5</item>
      <item>Item 6</item>
      <item>Item 7</item>
    </list>
  </text>
</section>
```

I am trying to find a way to have it output like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
    <td>Item 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

The way to do loops in Xslt is to use recursion.  There might be a shorter answer, but this works:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="helper"/>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="helper">
    <xsl:param name="columns" select="3"/>

    <!-- do not pass, used for recursion -->
    <xsl:param name="current-index" select="1"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(/section/text/list/item[position()=$current-index])"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="helper-row">
                    <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>

                    <xsl:with-param name="current-index" select="$current-index"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="current-column" select="1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </tr>

            <xsl:call-template name="helper">
                <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>

                <xsl:with-param name="current-index" select="$current-index + $columns"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="helper-row">
    <xsl:param name="columns"/>
    <xsl:param name="current-index"/>
    <xsl:param name="current-column"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(/section/text/list/item[position()=$current-index])"/>
        <xsl:when test="$current-column &lt;= $columns">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="/section/text/list/item[position()=$current-index]/text()"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:call-template name="helper-row">
                <xsl:with-param name="columns" select="$columns"/>

                <xsl:with-param name="current-index" select="$current-index + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current-column" select="$current-column + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In following stylesheet, you need to update the param 'limit' accordingly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="limit" select="'3'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="//item"/>
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(((count(//item) - (count(//item) mod xs:integer($limit))) div xs:integer($limit)) + 
                                        (if((count(//item) mod xs:integer($limit)) = 0) then 0 else 1))">
            <xsl:variable name="lower-limit" select="(position() - 1) * xs:integer($limit)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="upper-limit" select="position() * xs:integer($limit)"/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$list">
                    <xsl:if test="(position() gt xs:integer($lower-limit)) and (position() le xs:integer($upper-limit))">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```